# Why does not LayerA and LayerB make animation when it end Drag in Framerjs

Tags: framerjs

Why does not LayerA and LayerB make animation when it end Drag in Framerjs, with code:

I create `layerA`, `layerB` and `layerC`, then I drag `LayerC`.

In `Event DragMove`, I change `LayerA` and `LayerB`'s props with `LayerC`'s offset, and I always want to make a animation when it `EndDrag`, but it doesn't work.

Do someone knows why?

```
# Create layer
layerA = new Layer
    x: 50
    y: 200
    scale: 0.8
    width: 550
    height: 600
    opacity: 0.6
    borderRadius: 8
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff"

layerB = new Layer
    x: 50
    y: 250
    scale: 0.9
    opacity: 0.8
    width: 550
    height: 600
    borderRadius: 8
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff"

layerC = new Layer
    x: 50
    y: 300
    scale: 1
    width: 550
    height: 600
    borderRadius: 8
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff"

layerC.draggable.enabled = true
layerC.draggable.horizontal = false
layerC.draggable.constraints =
    x: 50
    y: 300
    width: 550
    height: 600
layerC.on Events.DragMove, ->
    print layerC.draggable.constraintsOffset
    layerA.opacity = 0.6 + 0.2 * layerC.draggable.constraintsOffset.y / 360
    layerA.scale = 0.8 + 0.1 * layerC.draggable.constraintsOffset.y / 360
    layerA.y = 200 + 50 * layerC.draggable.constraintsOffset.y / 360
    layerB.opacity = 0.8 + 0.2 * layerC.draggable.constraintsOffset.y / 360
    layerB.scale = 0.9 + 0.1 * layerC.draggable.constraintsOffset.y / 360
    layerB.y = 250 + 50 * layerC.draggable.constraintsOffset.y / 360

layerC.on Events.DragEnd, ->
    print layerC.draggable.constraintsOffset
    if layerC.draggable.constraintsOffset.y < 360
        layerC.animate
            properties: 
                opacity: 1
                scale: 1
                y: 300
            curve: "ease"
            time: 0.4
        layerA.animate 
        properties:
            opacity: 0.6
            scale: 0.8
            y: 200
        curve: "ease"
        time: 0.4
        layerB.animate 
        properties:
            opacity: 0.8
            scale: 0.9
            y: 250
        curve: "ease"
        time: 0.4
```

I am new to framer please make a help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your mistake was nothing in your thinking, you just forgot to intend the CoffeScript code for `layerA's` and `layerB's` animations properly. This is the working example I think:

http://share.framerjs.com/2mp2alhvueq4/

Regards from Germany,
Dennis

PS: The best way to ask questions according FramerJS / Framer Studio is our dedicated [Facebook-Group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/framerjs/).

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a better example of what you want to achieve?
Your code ( after fixing the formatting ) it worked - well, it fires the DragEnd event correctly, and calls the animations if the offset is less than 360.

If you tell us what you're trying to achieve, and share the framer project we can help you faster and more accurately.

*sorry for the request for info, I can't comment yet.